# Linking to openssl 64-bit static library

Tags: c++, visual-studio, openssl, linker, static-libraries

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 and I'm trying to link to openssl 1.0.2 built by me as 64-bit Release static library as shown [here](http://p-nand-q.com/programming/windows/building_openssl_with_visual_studio_2013.html). Actually it's my lib (also static) that is using openssl functions directly and executable is linking to this lib. I tried two approaches:

- Put openssl's symbols into mylib.lib (using a tab in VS mylib's project properties called "Librarian")
- Link to openssl (libeay32.lib, ssleay32.lib) and to my lib using Linker in executable's project

Both are resulting in linker errors like

```
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol EVP_EncryptInit_ex
```

concerning mylib.lib library.

I looked into libeay32.lib (also into mylib.lib while using the Librarian approach), using `dumpbin.exe` provided by Visual Studio, and there's `_EVP_EncryptInit_ex` (note the `_` at the beggining) symbol defined. So I'm wondering whether it is possible that openssl defines `_EVP_EncryptInit_ex` and the executable is trying to link to `EVP_EncryptInit_ex`? What could be the cause and solution? Also: How can I check for sure what symbols is exectuable trying to link to?

Comment: Yea, I know where it comes from, but the error message suggests that executable is looking for symbol without leading `_`. However I don't know if I'm right here

Comment: Pls post the steps you took to build openssl.

Comment: Solved, turns out I was initializing VC for 32bit build (`vsvars32.bat`) and ofc 64bit settings are needed (`vcvars64.bat`). Your question forced me to look up the building script again and I got the enlightment :)